# Javascript: Formula to get Direction from X, Y Coordinates

Tags: javascript, css, geometry, trigonometry, shadow

I was making a utility to quickly create CSS drop shadows, and realized that this can only be done in IE with [IE filters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847(v=vs.85).aspx). However, the [Shadow Filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533086(v=vs.85).aspx) uses Direction instead of (x, y) coordinates:

```
filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000');"
```

How can Direction be calculated from (x, y) coordinates?

**Edit:** Using the responses given and more details from [this link](http://www.teacherschoice.com.au/Maths_Library/Angles/Angles.htm): I modified my code as follows:

```
function(x, y){
    var d = Math.atan2(x, y) * (180 / Math.PI);
    if(d < 0){ d = 180 - d; }
    return d;
}
```

If you pass in Horizontal Offset and Vertical Offset that you would use as X, Y respectively, you will get a degree from 0 to 359.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Direction is in degrees.

So

```
x = cos(direction)
y = sin(direction)
```

If your calculator works in radians (as any sane calulator should), you can convert degrees to radians with

```
radians = degrees / 180 * pi
```

where pi = 3.14159... or Math.PI

To go the other way, use 'atan'

```
radians = Math.atan(y / x)
```

In Javascript you have a `Math.atan2` function which takes y and x as parameters.

```
radians = Math.atan2(y, x)
```

radians to degrees is:

```
degrees = radians / pi * 180
```

so the result is:

```
direction = Math.atan2(y,  x) / Math.PI * 180
```

Comment: +1: Good that you mentioned atan2; that's the right thing because it is hazard-free as long as at least one of the arguments is non-zero (unlike straight atan).